# Update date on datetime field without losing the format

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with two columns: `M_OP_DATE` (of type `DATE`) and `M__DT_UTC_DATE` (of type `TIMESTAMP(3)`). 
The table contains data as follows:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|      M_OP_DATE      |   M__DT_UTC_DATE    |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-09-03 00:00:00 | 2018-09-25 20:14:57 |
| 2018-08-31 00:00:00 | 2018-09-25 20:15:05 |
| 2018-08-31 00:00:00 | 2018-09-25 20:15:05 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to copy the date from `M_OP_DATE`, without touching the time, in the field `M__DT_UTC_DATE`.

I have searched on SO and found this answer which looked pretty much what I needed to do: [already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3408974/3111149).

I have hence adapted that answer to my data and come up with something like this:

```
update FXKAUD_H_DBF set M__DT_UTC_DATE = to_date(substr(M_OP_DATE, 0, 9) || ' ' || to_char(M__DT_UTC_DATE, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

However, the result was not the expected one:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|      M_OP_DATE      |   M__DT_UTC_DATE    |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-08-29 00:00:00 | 2029-08-18 14:47:07 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, the year is `2029` and the day is `18`. It basically swapped the two digits of the day with the two last digits of the year.

When I try just to select what's inside `substr(M_OP_DATE, 0, 9)`, I can see that it shows me the result differently than what I see in the table with a simple select:

```
select substr(M_OP_DATE, 0, 9) from FXKAUD_H_DBF

+-----------------------+
| SUBSTR(M_OP_DATE,0,9) |
+-----------------------+
| 29-AUG-18             |
+-----------------------+
```

... and it's when I try to format this string to date in format `YYYY-MM-DD` that the issue comes up:

```
select to_date(substr(M_OP_DATE, 0, 9), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from FXKAUD_H_DBF

| TO_DATE(SUBSTR(M_OP_DATE,0,9),'YYYY-MM-DD') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 0029-08-18 00:00:00                         |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Can anyone please guide me through the good approach? 
Sorry for not providing with a SQLfiddle, but the site is down for me (I'll check later if I can add it to the question).

Comment: try to use str_to_date function and NOT to_date : http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date

Comment: like this: SELECT STR_TO_DATE(M_OP_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM FXKAUD_H_DBF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select M_OP_DATE + (M__DT_UTC_DATE - trunc(M__DT_UTC_DATE))
```

Or:

```
select M__DT_UTC_DATE - (trunc(M__DT_UTC_DATE) - M_OP_DATE
```

The query will be:

```
update FXKAUD_H_DBF set M__DT_UTC_DATE = M__DT_UTC_DATE - (trunc(M__DT_UTC_DATE) - M_OP_DATE)
```